# How to prevent iframe from processing url's from an outside domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iframe

I'm working on a project where I need to restrict the iframe from displaying any url that we put in it other than the original domain.

for example, my website is www.myweb.com. having an iframe src="www.yourweb.com" should prevent anything to continue.

I have tried to use the frame-ancestor option in Content-Security-Policy. And X-Frame-Option to SAMEORIGIN/DENY. To no avail, nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'` should work, but it depends on an end-user browser. See [Headers to block iframe loading](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/07/20/block-iframe-loading/) for details and try both HTTP headers as described there.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions

especially

X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com/
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/